# Json type is not found within asp.net web api application

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this controller in my asp.net web api application :

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;  
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Mail;


namespace AjTransport.webApi.Controllers 
{
    public class AccountManageController : ApiController
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult FindUser(string str)
        {
            var result = UserManager.FindByName(str) ??   UserManager.FindByEmail(str);
             return Json(result == null, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
}
```

The problem is here

> return Json(result == null, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

the type **Json** is not found. So I need to know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this

```
return Json(result == null, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

to

```
return Json(result == null);
```

Also do not return a `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`, change that to.

```
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<bool> FindUser(string str)
```

This `System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is only valid for MVC and not WebAPI (*hint, see the name space of the type you are using*).

For more info on [ApiController.Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.json(v=vs.118).aspx) method see the link.